# JS Loop through the forms and for each add submit handler

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to submit my forms with js.
I have this code:

```
(function() {
  var handleSubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  
    var myForm = event.target;
    var formData = new FormData(myForm);
    
    fetch("/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(),
    })
      .then(() => console.log("Form successfully submitted"))
      .catch((error) => alert(error));
  };
  
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
  
  for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].onsubmit = handleSubmit(event);
  }
})();
```

But it does not works. I have an error (as soon as the site has loaded, even before submitting the form): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault').
What I should to fix there?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].onsubmit = handleSubmit;
}
```

Or alternatively

```
for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  forms[i].onsubmit = (event) => handleSubmit(event);
}
```

The error happens because you assign a result of calling `handleSubmit(event)` instead of a callback function. And at the time of calling it there exists no `event`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `= handleSubmit(event)` is executing the function instead of returning a function

You need

```
forms[i].addEventHandler('submit',handleSubmit);
```

but I suggest you delegate to a container instead

```
document.getElementById('formContainer').addEventHandler('submit',handleSubmit);
```

That container can be document:

```
document.addEventHandler('submit',handleSubmit);
```

where you have the same

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var myForm = event.target;
  var formData = new FormData(myForm);

  fetch("/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
    body: new URLSearchParams(formData).toString(),
   })
   .then(() => console.log("Form successfully submitted"))
   .catch((error) => alert(error));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Happening Because you are immediately execute the `handleSubmit` by `(function() {}) ()` see the brackets wrapping your function remove them to stop immediate execution like this `function(){}`

> Use Event handler like `onClick` of a button to invoke the function.

**CHANGE**

```
 for(var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].onsubmit = handleSubmit(event);
  }
```

**TO**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('form').forEach((el)=>el.addEventHandler('submit',(event) => handleSubmit(event)))
```

If you need more help just ask

Answer (score 1):

Adding to aantropov's answer, you can also register the submit handler for *all* forms (without a `for` loop) as follows:

```js
document.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit, true);
```